# How to manually input a row above the top row in a matrix?

Tags: matrix, documentation, keyboard

Assuming you already have a 3x3 matrix but now you want to manually input a row above the top row.
 How can I do that?
Pressing `Ctrl + Enter` only enter a row below an existing row so it does not seem to work.

Comment: Put the cursor on element {1,1}. The cursor should be blinking; i.e., don't select element {1,1}. Now press Ctrl-Enter.

Comment: Rows are stored as elements of a list. Therefore, to add a row at the beginning: Prepend[mat,row]

Comment: @Syed that works. Now how about if I have 3x3 matrix but I want to add 2 rows and 2 columns to 4 sides of the matrix? Add colums then you cannot apply the method you said to add row as it does not seem to work with empty element.

Comment: @DanielHuber yea but I want to input it manually in this case as I already had a matrix which is displayed in traditional form and now I just want to add a row or column it. So it's more human like to manually do that than a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

[image]

Better answer:

[image]

It seems like a work in progress (Esp. trying to Undo), but luckily many users have not much need for it.