# How to input a matrix like the following picture?

Tags: matrix

i want to input matrix like the following

[image]

now my method is: Insert -> Table/Matrix -> New -> input the row and column, but i hate the method, i want sth like shortcut key, i guess there a way create 1×1 matrix and i can use some shortcut key to expand row and column. Anyway, i just want a more efficient and comfortable way to input the content of the above picture. how do you input this?

Comment: Check [282511](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282511/entering-matrices-interactively).

Comment: "Ctrl  comma" will insert a row and "Ctrl Enter" will insert the corresponding columns.

Comment: Also see: [257605](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257605/how-to-manually-input-a-row-above-the-top-row-in-a-matrix/257615#257615)